# Which plants produce the most income in the Daytime Zen Garden?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

I have nearly filled up my Daytime Zen Garden.  I have mostly Marigolds, but I also have a Walnut and a Pea Shooter which I found during Adventure mode.  To maximize the coins produced by the daytime Zen Garden, should I sell the Marigolds or the randomly dropped plants when I need more room in my daytime zen garden?

Comment: Been a long time, but IIRC marigolds give the least and then most everything else is pretty much equal, then the mushrooms/aquatic plants which give bonuses

Comment: I actually found I was losing money by keeping the marigolds around (on PC). I think it's best to buy Marigolds, build them up to full plants, and sell them. I kept the unique plants I found

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have collected some data from my Zen Garden in which I planted half Marigolds, and half other plants - the screen shots are below.

Over all the screenshots, each half of the garden produced 16 Gold coins. I didn't count the Silver coins, but it looks about equal.  So it seems to me that Marigolds and other plants produce about the same amount of coinage when left unattended.  **However, Marigolds only sell for 3000g, while other plants sell for 8000g when fully grown,** so that's probably only in selling to Dave that the non-Marigolds are more profitable.

[image: 50/50 Zen Garden 1 of 5]

[image: 50/50 Zen Garden 2 of 5]

[image: 50/50 Zen Garden 3 of 5]

[image: 50/50 Zen Garden 4 of 5]

[image: 50/50 Zen Garden 5 of 5]

Answer (score 2):

Mushrooms and aquatic plants give a lot more than daytime plants. (Note that the grave buster is actually a "daytime" plant!)

Comment: Is there a way that I can get fully grown Nighttime and Aquatic plants to live in my Daytime garden?

Comment: No, there is not